# Выдаёт ошибку Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException в файле ввода input.txt. В нём содержится +34

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("input.txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
        int n;
        int i;
        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
        n = in.nextInt();
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a.add(in.nextInt());
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (a.get(i) == -a.get(j)) {
                    a.remove(i);
                    a.remove(j);
                }
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(a.get(i));
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это ваш код? В нем написано, что считывается первый integer, задающий количество integer'ов, которые еще предстоит считать. А потом считывается это количество integer'ов. Ваш nextInt() банально не находит integer, так как "+31" - не число. "31" - уже число. Если записать в файл "2 31 23", то консоль программа выведет 31 и 23.

Comment: Да, это мой код. Суть в том, что "+" должен обозначаться, как добавление элемента, а "-" удаление элемента. Получается, что мне нужно вначале принять эти данные как строку, а после, так как это будет двоичная матрица вычленить цифры и преобразовать их в стринговую форму.

Comment: Да. Делаете split(" "), Потом прогоняете через for String[], в котором детектите с помощью string[i].charAt(0) == '+', тогда add(Integer.parseInt( string[i].substring(1))); И так по аналогии для '-'